# htaccess file issue for multiple application in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I am running 3 application in one codeigniter. When i run 1st app i type //localhost/foldername it runs well, when i run 2nd app it takes  localhost/foldername/admin.php and when i run 3rd app it takes localhost/foldername/project.php i want to remove .php 
i have tried with this.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]



 My Application Structure is like :
    -abc
    --application-htaccess
    --application2-htaccess
    --application3-htaccess
    --assets
    --systems
    --uploads
    --htaccess
    --index.php
    --application2.php
    --application3.php
```

URL:localhost/abc/application1/------------error----Directory access is forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Add this `.htaccess` in all apps. It's work for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have added code to all app and it says "Directory access is forbidden."

Comment: you have add this `.htaccess` in your app root folder?

Comment: i have added in all htaccess files inside all application also